# Maze matrix reduction

Tags: matrices

I'd like to have a bit of advice on a problem I'm facing.

I'm developing an app for solving mazes. In this app, I represent a maze using a matrix. Each cell corresponds to a pixel with 1 meaning a wall and 0 meaning a corridor. The problem is that this matrix is too big, so I'm looking for a way to reduce its size by trimming close cells with the same values.

Here's an example of what I'd like:

```
Original            ->     Wanted
11111111111               11111111111
10000000000               10000000000
10000000000               10111111111
10000000000               10100000000
10001111111               10111111111
10011111111               
10011000000
10011111111
```

Is there any existing mathematical algorithm/formula I can apply to my matrix to get this result?

Thanks

Comment: You have to define "close cells with the same values" precisely before anyone can answer, but I'd guess that you'll need a computer program, not a formula.

Comment: In the wanted matrix, should you merge the 8 columns to the right too?

Comment: They could be merged too, it's not compulsory but it's fine if they merge

Comment: Have you consider using a sparse matrix library for whatever language you are using? You should be able to find packages that offer optimal solutions for this kind of problem

Comment: Yeah but I don't think a sparse matrix would help in my case. In practice, my algorithm keeps track of the visited "pixels", so even if I reduce the size of the matrix this way my problem will be the same because basically the number of elements on the matrix would be the same (even if the representation is different)...